# Select a Tab without invoking OnTabSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to use TabLayout in my Activity. Each Tab takes user to a fragment.

1. Suppose user is on Tab1 which has fragment1.
2. He clicks Tab2 which has fragment2.
3. Now when user is on Tab2 and presses back button I want user to go back to Fragment1 on Tab1. I do this by doing `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`.Now I also want to update selected tab to Tab1.

Is there any way I can mark a tab as selected in TabLayout without invoking TabSelectedListener?

Answer (score 6):

just do this:

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(index);

tabLayout.removeOnTabSelectedListener(this);
tab.select();
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
```

enjoy:)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever code you're running in `onTabSelected` can be moved into a custom method and you can maintain the active tab state within your activity.

1. Add a field for the currently active tab position
2. Create an `onTabSelected(int position, boolean update)` method.  Passing false as the second parameter bypasses whatever logic you're looking to avoid running when programmatically selecting your tab.
3. Before calling `tab.select()` to update the `TabLayout`, call `onTabSelected(position, false)` to update the active tab field you created in step one but without running your tab selected logic.  Then when your `TabSelectedListener` fires, it'll short circuit because the `activeTabPosition` field will already have been set to the updated position.

Here's the skeleton of the new method.

```
    private void onTabSelected(int position, boolean update) {
        if (position == activeTabPosition) {
            return;
        }

        activeTabPosition = position;
        if (update) {
            // Your tab selected logic
        }
    }
```